# passing element id by javascript function to xajax php function

Tags: php, javascript, xajax

i am checking username availabilty by using xajax function I want it on anchar tag click. I am doing it like `onclick="xajax_checkusername('getElementByid(\"username\").value')`. but it is not working.  lease help

Comment: onclick="xajax_checkusername('getElementByid(\"username\").value')" I am calling this on button say. checkusername($username) is php function

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly passing the parameter, remove the single quotes so it becomes

```
onclick="xajax_checkusername(document.getElementByid('username').value)"
```

Note that this kind of inline Javascript is not recommended as it will become a maintenance nightmare

Comment: it there other way to pass this

Comment: 'not working' is not enough information, do you see any error in your console? F12

Comment: Username: <input name="username" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('username');?>" id="username" size="26" maxlength="15" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="myDiv"></span><a id="checkUsername" name="checkUsername" class="loginlink" onclick="xajax_checkUsername(document.getElementByid('username').value)" href="javascript:void(0)">Check Availability</a> these are form elements

Comment: please update your question with the code, comments are not meant for whole chunks of code

Answer (score 1):

Please Use;

onclick="xajax_checkusername(xajax.$('username').value);"

username field ID tag value must be "username"
e.g.

Answer (score 0):

In your example

```
getElementByid(\"username\").value
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("username").value // id should be ID
```

Comment: onclick="xajax_checkUsername('document.getElementById(\'username\').value')" this is also not working

Comment: `\'username\'` should be `'username'`.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
onclick=\"xajax_checkusername(getElementById('username').value))\";
```